# What is the meaning and origin of «агитлисток»?

Tags: перевод

I encountered the word while reading a Russian article about media.

> Если не сказать ее агитлисток.

I was unable to find a translation for it by search engine. I assume it is derogatory in the sense of propaganda from context but I am just guessing. Can someone provide a better sense of the word?

Comment: A translation is available online at [Multitran](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=3&s=%E0%E3%E8%F2%EB%E8%F1%F2%EE%EA.&sc=0&l1=2&l2=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Агитлисток` is a shortened form of `Агитационный листок`.
Literally this could be translated as

> Agitational sheet

or (depending on context)

> Propaganda leaflet

Comment: Yes, and there is nothing derogatory about the term. In the Soviet times they liked compound abbreviations: компартия, политинформация, комсомол. Агитлисток is one of those. It is simply a flyer, not necessarily a leaflet.

Comment: A parallel term in English is "agitprop".